# How can I make my python script determine if a number is an integer or a floating point depending on the mode its set to?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that would take a user inputted number and determine if the number is an integer or a floating-point depending on what the mode is set to. I am very new to python and learning the language and I am getting an invalid syntax error and I don't know what to do. So far I am making the integer tester first. Here is the code:

```
def getNumber(IntF, FloatA, Msg, rsp):
    print("What would you like to do?")
    print("Option A = Interger")
    print("Option B = Floating Point")
      
Rsp = int(input("What number would like to test as an interger?"))

A = rsp

if rsp == "A":
    while True:
      try:
        userInput = int(input("What number would like to test as an interger"))

        except ValueError as ve:
         print("Not an integer! Try again.")
         continue
    else:
      return userInput 
      break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code you shared is :

- The syntax error you mentioned is probably because the `except` clause has to be at the same indentation level as `try`, and same for `if` and `else` of the same if/else clause. All the code in the function should be indented 1 level too. Python requires all this to identify blocks of code.
- You don't need to give 4 arguments to the `getNumber()` function if you're not using them. This isn't really a problem, but you'll have to pass it some 4 values each time you call it (for example `getNumber(1,2,3,4)` etc...) to avoid missing argument errors; and these won't matter because you're not doing anything with the given values inside the function - so it's a little wasted effort. I rewrote it in the example below so that you aren't dealing with more variables than you need - it makes the code clearer/simpler.
- You also don't need `break` after a `return` statement because the return will exit the enitre function block, including the loop.

Try this and see if it makes sense - I've changed a lot of the code :

```py
def getNumber():
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = int(input("What number would like to test as an integer ? "))
            return userInput
        except ValueError as ve:
            print("Not an integer! Try again.")
            continue

print("What would you like to do?")
print("Option A = Interger")
print("Option B = Floating Point")
chosen_option = input()
if chosen_option == 'A':
    integer_received = getNumber()
    print(integer_received, "was an int !")
else:
    print("You did not choose 'A' or 'B'")
```

Answer (score 0):

**To determine whether a number is a float or integer, you can use this approach**

float is nothing but the integer with floating-point(.).
to determine this we first need to convert it to string and find does it contain a point or not.

```
    number = input("Enter a numbeer\n")
    if number.find(".") == -1:
    # find will return -1 when the value is not in string
        print("it is integer")
    else:
        print("it is float")
```

Comment: please ignore spelling mistakes